# Force Eagerly load all dependencies in Hibernate

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading

Most of our Entities have Lazy loading as they are not required.
In one specific scenario,function requires them to load eagerly, which is out of Transaction Scope.

Here's the bit of implementation

```
@Transaction
public E getFullyLoadedDetachedEntity(Long id) {
    E entity = dao.findById(id);
    Hibernate.initialize(entity);
    dao.detach(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

But the problem is, `Entity(E) might have associated entities 'X' which might have 'Y' as lazy loaded.`

```
class E{
   X x; //Lazy Load
}
class X{
   Y y; //Lazy load
}
```

Now, `Hibernate.initialize(entity) may be loading only it's associated entities(X) but not the associated entites(Y) of X.`

How do I forcefully load all of the dependencies/Lazy loaded objects at any level.

**Update**
I tried this one though

```
E entity = dao.findById(id);
Hibernate.initialize(entity);
for (X x : entity.getXList()) {
    Hibernate.initialize(x);
}
dao.detach(entity);
```

I am still getting LazyException on accessing the X.getY()

Comment: `Hibernate.initialize(entitity.getX());` will do it for that level, but if you head down that path, it won't be long before you are pulling nearly your entire database into memory

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more line to your updated code.

```
E entity = dao.findById(id);
Hibernate.initialize(entity);
for (X x : entity.getXList()) {
    Hibernate.initialize(x);
    Hibernate.initialize(x.getY());
}
dao.detach(entity);
```

Hope this helps you :)